# Oracle APEX 20.2 Email Sending

Tags: oracle, apex, push-queue

I done the email configuration and done the email sending code in oracle apex page, but unable to send emails properly, some time it works smoothly but all of a sudden it stuck and my emails appear in mail queue, can anyone guide me no this that what things are missing in the process?

Comment: Emails will stay in `apex_mail_queue` if there is an error sending the email. For the emails that are "stuck", is there a value in the `MAIL_SEND_ERROR` column of that view?

Comment: this column is blank

Comment: Do the emails send if you call `APEX_MAIL.PUSH_QUEUE`?

Comment: emails are sent by a scheduler job. Check ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS to make sure it is enabled and running successfully at regular intervals.

Comment: It's done, Thanks for the guidance and help